# issues with creating a new object in a class

Tags: php, oop

Eclipse is giving me a red line under new for my Person object. I was wondering what is wrong with my code. I am new to OOP in php.

```
class Matcher{
private $user1= new Person($firstName, $lastName, $zipCode, $hairColor, $job,         $eyeColor, $height, $weight, $dateOfBirth, $children, $education, $ethnicity, $faith, $language, $bodyType);
private $user2= Person;

function __construct($user1, $user2){
    $this -> user1 = $user1;
    $this -> user2 = $user2;
}

}
```

Comment: I highly recommend learning basic php syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in your class constructor:

```
class Matcher{

private $user1
private $user2;

    function __construct($user1, $user2){

       $this->user1 = new Person($firstName, $lastName, $zipCode, $hairColor, $job,         $eyeColor, $height, $weight, $dateOfBirth, $children, $education, $ethnicity, $faith, $language, $bodyType);                
       $this->user2 = new Person();
    }

}
```

But in addition I don't see any point why you create new objects here as you in constructor also assign other objects (or variables) to properties `user1` and `user2` .

Also for `user2` you had incorrect syntax `private $user2= Person;` without new operator

Comment: I was also trying things to get it to work. I didn't know I could use a type parameter in my constructor.